# Discord API "Cannot send an empty message"

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord

I'm trying to manually respond to a discord API call by getting the token from the logs of my API but when i send the request, it responds with

```
<Response [400]>
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

Code is below:

```
import requests

application_id = "9999999999032"
payload = {"type": 4,
                "data": {"content": "Congrats on sending your command!"}}
interaction_token = "aW50****lm"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.patch(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/webhooks/{application_id}/{interaction_token}/messages/@original", headers=headers, json=payload)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

Link to docs https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-response-object-interaction-callback-type

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested your code yet, but I think the problem is in the **payload** variable, instead of doing this:

```
{
    "type": 4,
    "data": {
        "content": "Congrats on sending your command!"
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
{
    "type": 4,
    "content": "Congrats on sending your command!"
}
```

If it doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it.